# react native get cookies

Tags: cookies, react-native

I had logined in my server with fetch(),I want to know how I get the cookies.

I know that I can use "*document.cookie*" to get the cookies in a web browser development,but in react native develop how?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

I just came across the same problem.
My first approach was to manually get the cookies from the response headers.
This become more difficult since `Headers.prototype.getAll` was removed (see [this issue](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/506)).
The details are shown further down below.

#### Getting and parsing cookies might be unnecessary

First, I want to mention that all the below cookie parsing turned out to be unnecessary because the implementation of `fetch` on *React Native* sends the cookies automatically (if the `credentials` key is set correctly).
So the session is kept (just like in the browser) and further `fetch`es will work just fine.
Unfortunately, the React Native documentation on *Networking* does not explicitly tell you that it'll work out of the box. It only says: "React Native provides the Fetch API for your networking needs."

#### First approach

Thus, I wrote a helper function:

```js
// 'headers' is iterable
const get_set_cookies = function(headers) {
    const set_cookies = []
    for (const [name, value] of headers) {
        if (name === "set-cookie") {
            set_cookies.push(value)
        }
    }
    return set_cookies
}

fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin", // or 'include' depending on CORS
    // ...
})
.then(response => {
    const set_cookies = get_set_cookies(response.headers)
})
```

To parse the cookie strings into objects I used [set-cookie-parser](https://github.com/nfriedly/set-cookie-parser).
This way I wanted send the cookies back manually like

```js
import SetCookieParser from "set-cookie-parser"

const cookies_to_send = set_cookies
    .map(cookie => {
        const parsed_cookie = SetCookieParser.parse(cookie)
        return `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}`
    })
    .join('; ')

fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin", // or 'include' depending on CORS
    headers: {
        Cookie: cookies_to_send,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
})
```

Comment: Do you know how to do a fetch without the cookies? I tried `fetch('...', { method:'POST', credentials:'omit' }` but it always has cookies.

Comment: i am unable to get "set-cookie" parameter in response headers in fetch api in android. in ios i am getting it for first time. how to get "set-cookie" every time i login in both android and ios.
i used to achieve this in native ios by setting setHTTPShouldHandleCookies to NO.
thanks in advance.

Comment: @Noitidart I doesn't yet seem to be trivial. I haven't tried it but [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1274#issuecomment-346214040) seems helpful. Dhanunjay: I am currently not developing for Android so I have not much experience there. But since cookies are handled on the non-JavaScript side ([source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1274#issuecomment-102221311) - but it's from 2015...maybe RN 0.55 does something differently) I think you have to use a third-party library like [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies).